# How to solve ExceptionConverter com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.TableWrapper cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.TextElementArray

Tags: html, itext

My objective of using below code is to convert the HTML file to PDF

```
 try {
      com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A4);
      PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:\\CreateHTMLToPDF.pdf"));
      document.open();
      document.addAuthor("Real Gagnon");
      document.addCreator("Real's HowTo");
      document.addSubject("Thanks for your support");
      document.addCreationDate();
      document.addTitle("Please read this");

      HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
      String str = "<html>"+
                "<head></head>"+
              "<table><body>"+
                "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>"+
                    "<tr>"+
                    "<th width='100%' height='30px' style='background-color:#00FF00'><h1>Result</h1></th>"+
                    "</tr>"+ 
                "</table>"+
                "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>"+  
                    "<tr>"+
                    "<th width='100%' height='50px'></th>"+
                    "</tr>"+ 
                "</table>"+
                "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>"+   
                    "<tr>"+
                    "<th width='30%' height='440px'></th>"+
                    "<th width='30%' height='440px'></th>"+
                    "<th width='30%' height='220px'></th>"+
                    "</tr>"+  
                "</table>"+
                "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>"+   
                    "+<tr>"+
                    "<th width='100%' height='200px'></th>"+
                    "</tr>"+ 
                "</table>"+
            "</body></table>"+
      "</html>";
      htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(str));
      document.close();
      System.out.println("Done");
      } catch(DocumentException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

It's throwing below exception, when i used htmlWorker object,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.TableWrapper cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.TextElementArray
    at com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.processTable(HTMLWorker.java:599)
    at com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLTagProcessors$11.endElement(HTMLTagProcessors.java:363)
    at com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.endElement(HTMLWorker.java:238)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.processTag(SimpleXMLParser.java:590)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.go(SimpleXMLParser.java:341)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.parse(SimpleXMLParser.java:608)
    at com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.parse(HTMLWorker.java:154)
    at com.project.Html2Pdf.main(HtmlToPDF.java:71)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your html is broken:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <table>
    <body>
      ...
    </body>
  </table>
</html>
```

You essentially wrap your `body` in a `table` but the body must be an immediate child of `html`

Comment: But not display pdf  same Like  HTML Page Display,  My Requirement Same Page create For PDF Look like Same

Comment: how can create multiple tables and how add in one PDF

Comment: A HTML renderer should **reject** that HTML, it is invalid. Your requirement to render invalid HTML identical on different renderers should be rejected.

Comment: The `table` elements *inside* your body look ok. Remove the invalid *outer* one.

Comment: ok,  I removed.  PDF is creating. But not Display Same like Html Page display

Comment: @Ban Of course, it doesn't display the same: (1) HTML and PDF are very different technologies; what is possible in HTML isn't necessarily possible in PDF and vice-versa. (2) Moreover: you are using `HTMLWorker` **and you shouldn't do that!** Use [XML Worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker). See the [examples](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker) and read the [free ebook](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) (it has a chapter on HTML to PDF conversion).

Comment: But  I am using XML Worker then I m getting Exception Like java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Element not allowed.